# python3 inside venv gives termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')

Tags: python, linux, pipenv, tty, ioctl

I've been running a python script inside a virtual environment that I create with `pipenv shell`, it worked well.

I've always run the process from a bash script that changes directory to the folder containing the python script, activates the virtualenv with `pipenv shell`, then runs the python script, then exits the virtualenv.

However, I must have typed something wrong in the terminal and broke something, now I get this when I run the script inside the virtual environment:

```
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/manuel/.local/bin/pipenv", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/home/manuel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/manuel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/manuel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/manuel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/manuel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/manuel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/manuel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/manuel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 429, in shell
    do_shell(
  File "/home/manuel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 2387, in do_shell
    shell.fork_compat(*fork_args)
  File "/home/manuel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/shells.py", line 121, in fork_compat
    c.interact(escape_character=None)
  File "/home/manuel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 788, in interact
    mode = tty.tcgetattr(self.STDIN_FILENO)
termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

I have uninstalled and re-installed `pipenv` but to no avail.

If I run the script without activating the virtual environment, I don't get the error above, but   I have other issues.

What is causing this error? How can I get rid of it? Thanks.

Comment: One year later, I don't remember what I did to solve this issue, but I have learned since then that it's better to use `pipenv run` and also that it helps to use absolute paths to the pipenv executable (to the output of `which pipenv` that I want to use). So now I use, say, `/usr/local/bin/pipenv run python3.8 path/to/script.py` and it goes well. I hope this helps other people.